# Do not evaluate variable in foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have a bunch of variables defined with similar names, e.g.:

```
\def\wstepsA{1/2/0,2/3.5/1};
```

All variables have a name `wsteps` + a letter, and I want to iterate over them using tikz's `foreach`:

```
\foreach \v in {A, ..., F} {
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\thisSteps\csname wsteps\v\endcsname
    \foreach \s/\e/\d in {\thisSteps} {
        % Do something...
    }
}
```

But this gives me an error:

> Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide '0.5' by '0', but I cannot divide any number by '0' (in '1/2/0').

But if I do not use a variable `thisSteps`, this works fine:

```
\foreach \s/\e/\d in {1/2/0,2/3.5/1} {

}
```

Is there a way to make the first snippet working?

Comment: You should use `\foreach \s/\e/\d in \thisSteps` without `{}`

Comment: @Kpym Forget my previous command, this works within a MCVE, so the new error is somewhere else. You can post this as an answer if you want.

Comment: @Kpym Care for an answer?

Comment: @percusse I'm on vacation, so if somebody can answer it , I'll be ok with that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the iterators are given to a foreach macro it treats the contents as a grouped entity. That is to say wrapped around a curly brace. Here because you add extra `{}` TikZ tries to see where the comma is but can't find it and decides that `\thisSteps` is the only element and the loop spins only once assigning `\s`, to `1/2/0` which results in divide by zero.

Hence as Kpym (aka TikZer Woods) mentioned you have to strip off the braces for TikZ to expand it and check its contents.